# Will Ubuntu enable RANDOM_TRUST_CPU in the kernel and what would be the effect?

Tags: boot, kernel, security, cpu

According to this [The Register article from 2018-08-28](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2018/08/28/linux_419_trust/) and other articles, the Linux kernel version 4.19 will have a compilation flag named `RANDOM_TRUST_CPU`. Here's also a [link to a mailing list entry](https://lkml.org/lkml/2018/7/17/1279) by the patch author, including the actual code changes.
From what I understood, this will allow systems to speed up the boot process under some circumstances, by *not* waiting until enough entropy is gathered from various sources to securely seed the random number generator, but skipping that part and relying solely on the CPU's built-in random number generator.

This would weaken the system's cryptographic security, as it would (if I understand this correctly) not only rely on just the CPU as a single entropy source, but also can completely undermine security if that CPU's implementation is not trustworthy (bugs, intentional backdoors, ...).

- Would the kernel's random number generator then be initialized only from the CPU's generator for the whole time, or will it just do that during the early boot stages and add more entropy from the "traditional" sources into the pool later, increasing the cryptographic security over time again back to the current/old level?
- As this apparently is a compile time flag, will the kernel packages provided in Ubuntu's repositories come with this flag enabled or disabled?
- Might there be a way to opt-in or opt-out, other than compiling kernels oneself from now on?
- Is there a way to actually test if this would make a difference in boot time? Are there currently any metrics available about time spent waiting for entropy during boot?
- And which Ubuntu releases will even get to run 4.19 or later kernel versions?

Comment: It is not set in Ubuntu's kernel configuration file for [kernel 4.19-rc1](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.19-rc1/), meaning it is not compiled in. From looking at the patch, it appears to be only a compile time opt-in or opt-out option.

Comment: It is not set for 4.19 final either.

Answer (score 7):

First, reasonably, the system's cryptographic security - its unpredictability -, is not going to be altered in any way, regardless of whether the CPU's built-in HWRNG (e.g. `RDRAND` in Intel) is used or not, otherwise, as you noted, that would unavoidably weaken the security of the RNG (and anything that depends on it).

Briefly, just to sum up, during the bootstrapping process, after the kernel has loaded the randomness driver, the Linux RNG [initializes](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/420f51f4ab6bce6e580390729fadb89c31123636/drivers/char/random.c#L1809) all the random pools (*entropy pools*, which are just memory areas that hold random data), including the main pool (*input pool*), by populating them with entropy which comes from the HWRNG if it is available, otherwise via `random_get_entropy()`, which is a macro for `get_cycles()`, whose implementation varies with the architecture (e.g. in aarch64 a read of the `CNTVCT_EL0` register [is done](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/420f51f4ab6bce6e580390729fadb89c31123636/arch/arm64/include/asm/arch_timer.h#L160), which is kind of a frequency counter, not actually the clock rate which is instead used in x86-64 by reading the TSC reg). All this data is given to a primary cipher state (`primary_crng`, an object of type `struct crng_state`, which is the implementation of the [ChaCha20 algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salsa20)), which contains a key of 384 truly random bits, which are eventually supplied to the `/dev/urandom` interface.

Now with this contextualization, to answer your question, kernel's RNG actual initialization through `rand_initialize()`, being an `early_initcall`, happens obviously only at boot time (like all the `*_initcall()`), particularly, at the very end of `start_kernel()`, the kernel routine `rest_init()` gets called where, one of the first things it does, is to spawn a kernel thread (`kernel_init`) with the purpose, among other things, to launch that initcall (note also that `add_device_randomness()` is called even [before](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/420f51f4ab6bce6e580390729fadb89c31123636/init/main.c#L558), but doesn't actually add any entropic data); and consequently yes, per source, the cipher state of the ChaCha20, the primary and the blocking pools would be initialized with `arch_get_random_long()`, which makes use of the `RDRAND` instruction in x86 processors (again, if it's available, and if it is, the kernel [warns you](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/420f51f4ab6bce6e580390729fadb89c31123636/drivers/char/random.c#L805) about this). I wouldn't say it's the only source used though (even if `RDRAND` is available), because, at least:

1. The firmware time is used and is mixed into the pools [during the initialization](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/420f51f4ab6bce6e580390729fadb89c31123636/drivers/char/random.c#L1789) (maybe not that entropic, still an attacker would have to infer the timestamp with an extremely high precision);
2. There's another little pool (one per CPU, called *fast pool*), which collects entropy from `add_interrupt_randomness()`, which uses IRQs (and theoretically other kernel events, and even some seed coming from the CPU hardware RNG if there is) as input, all mixed, and then it's injected into the input pool. This happens like every second.

So the process of gathering entropy from both the HWRNG and the other sources happens all together; of course the first one dominates the scene (because the entropy quality is definitely higher, it's a true RNG), and occurs at boot time, and, from userspace, whenever the pseudorandom devices (or the `getrandom()` syscall) are used. In the second case though, the pools are already initialized, and just the `primary_crng` (the cipher state) is reseeded. And yes, as you noted, the CPU built-in RNG surely improves the overall randomness.

I would finally add, that, especially in the embedded systems, which may lack of some source noise (like keyboards, hard disks, etc.), the usage of the HWRNG would have a significant impact. And just note that, always [per documentation](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/0519359784328bfa92bf0931bf0cff3b58c16932/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt#L2926), you could disable the kernel usage of `RDRAND` way before the introduction of `RANDOM_TRUST_CPU`, if you're concerned with security.

Comment: +1 for being one of the most technically advanced first time user answer I've read.